# Необходимо процитировать точно

Tags: цитата

В сентябре премьер-министр, возглавляющий антимиграционный лагерь, заявил о важности «защиты наших границ» для сохранения Европы.

Можно ли так смешивать прямую  и косвенную речь, если необходимо подчеркнуть точность сказанных слов -- «защиты наших границ»?

Answer (score 4):

Можно так оформить цитату, но **при условии,** если: 1) пишущий и премьер-министр принадлежат одной стране и это всем известно,  2) статья выходит в этой же стране. Ясно, что сказал премьер-министр именно так: *защита наших границ*. Он мог сказать *защита границ государства*, ещё как-то. А он сказал "наших".

Если же пишут о премьер-министре **другой** страны, то так цитировать **нельзя** из-за того же слова **"наших"**. Придётся оформить полное высказывание в виде предложения с прямой речью и назвать страну, которую представляет премьер-министр. *В сентябре премьер-министр Такой-то страны, возглавляющий антимиграционный лагерь,  заявил: "Очень важна защита наших границ..."* Тогда будет понятно, что имел в виду министр, говоря "наших", - границы своей страны.

Если же он имел в виду границы нескольких  стран, то предложенный вами вариант цитаты **тоже некорректен.** Необходимо цитирование полного  высказывания и уточнение того, что имел в виду премьер-министр, говоря **"наших"**.

***Так что лучше сразу оформить цитату в виде предложения с прямой речью и привести высказывание полностью, сопроводив его необходимой иформацией в части "слова автора".***